# Inserting legend title in Geonode?

Tags: legend, geonode, title

How can include a title legend (instead of legend) in geonode?

I have tried with everything but I can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

It can be changed in in [layer details template](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/master/geonode/layers/templates/layers/layer_detail.html#L558)

```
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{%trans "Legend" %}</h4>
```

this file located in /geonode/layers/templates/layers/layer_detail.html